# macOS SwiftUI: Constraining window minimum width based on child minimum widths

Tags: macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

My app has a main document window that contains a List on the left, some detail on the right:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0 ..< 5) { layer in
                NavigationLink(destination: LayerDetail()) {
                    LayerItemCell()
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 200.0)
        }
    }
```

[image]

I’ve specified minimum widths for both the `List` view and the detail view on the right. Unfortunately, as I shrink the window such that both the list and detail view would be forced to shrink below their minimums, SwiftUI makes the list disappear, instead of constraining the window to that minimum size:

[image]

What I really want is for the window to not shrink that small. But I don’t really want to add a `.frame(minWidth:)` constraint, because then I have two places in the code to check if the design changes.

Lastly, how do I keep the little status bar under the image pinned to the left? Each `Text` view has a specific width, and when the window gets too narrow, it pushes the `HStack` off to the left, rather than truncating to the right:

[image]

I tried all sorts of `.frame(alignment: .leading)` on various parts of the view hierarchy, but none seemed to do what I want. The views are left-aligned until the window gets too small, at which point they begin to center (and truncate left and right).

It really seems like `.frame()` doesn’t work well (e.g. I can't make `idealWidth` do anything). But maybe I’m just using it wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59238741/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi no, unfrotunately, that's for the pre-Scenes SwiftUI. I just had to put `.frame(minWidth: 301)` on the top-level view for now (the sum of the list and detail minimum widths, +1) to work around it. And I reported it to Apple.