# SwiftUI iOS app on mac: how to allow smaller window size than (default) iPad equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app originally coded for iOS, that I would like to run at mac as well. I have checked `Mac` in `Deployment info` section, but the problem is that the app starts in an iPad-sized window that cannot be resized to a smaller size by user.

I would like to

- allow the window to be resized to a smaller than default size
- start the app with a smaller window size (that looks like iPhone app running in a window)

I tried adding frame modifier to ContentView like this, but it didn't accomplish anything:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var appState = AppState()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appState)
                // this is an attempt to start the app at 'iPhone-like' size
                .frame(minWidth: 320, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 480, idealHeight: 480, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

Here are project settings:
[image]

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59238417/how-do-i-set-the-minimum-window-size-with-swiftui-and-how-do-i-make-the-window) gives you some ideas?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I've seen this, the second, newer answer (setting a frame on contentview) doesn't do anything for me. I'll see if the first one would help, but really, I'd rather not invoke NSWindow from SwiftUI unless absolutely needed ...